# Run conky over LightDM

Tags: lightdm, login-screen, conky

Is it possible to have my conky gadgets run over my lightDM login screen?  If so, how would I go about this?  I saw someone doing it with XDM under debian in this screenshot from a [thread on the archlinux forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=122445)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is.

The idea is that you edit your lightdm configuration file (`/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`)
and set the `greeter-setup-script` variable to start conky.

A complete example might be found at:
http://vogelchr.blogspot.com.br/2012/11/ligthdm-custom-app-on-login-screen.html

Comment: For this to work you need to start conky with `-p 1` (or whatever works for you) and have `own_window yes` in the config file.

Comment: Okay, it seems you also need `own_window_type override` in the config.

Comment: Sigh — even with this, it only works occasionally.